# How to improve sort performance in a huge dataset of 20 million rows?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

So I have this query which is extremely slow to run -

```
SELECT
    "conversation".*,
    "teamBotLocation"."id" AS "teamBotLocation.id",
    "teamBotLocation"."name" AS "teamBotLocation.name"
FROM
    "conversation" AS "conversation"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "teamBotLocation" AS "teamBotLocation" ON "conversation"."teamBotLocationId" = "teamBotLocation"."id"
WHERE
    "conversation"."teamBotId" = 'some_id'
    AND "conversation"."teamBotLocationId" IN ('some_id','some_id')
    AND "conversation"."isDeleted" = false
    AND "conversation"."isBlocked" = false
    AND "conversation"."isBroadcast" = false
    AND "conversation"."isGroup" = false
ORDER BY
     CASE
         WHEN "firstName" = '' THEN NULL
         ELSE 0
     END ASC NULLS LAST,
    "conversation"."firstName" NULLS LAST,"conversation"."id" DESC
LIMIT
    10 OFFSET 100;
```

What this query actually does ?

So I have a conversation table that has almost 20 million rows. And I am displaying all these conversations in a table with a default limit of 10. We are sorting the table by these 5 columns `firstName`, `lastName`, `phone`, `email` and `createdAt` in ascending/descending order.

I am currently using this query in production. For smaller no. of results the execution time is below 1s which is fine. But when results are in millions let's say 1 million then the execution time is too slow well around 10s. I found out that the primary reason for the slowness is sorting.

**This is my query plan in text** -

```
Limit  (cost=353265.17..353265.20 rows=10 width=1742) (actual time=130013.935..130013.939 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=353265.17..353481.27 rows=86438 width=1742) (actual time=130013.934..130013.937 rows=10 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: (CASE WHEN ((conversation.""firstName"")::text = ''::text) THEN NULL::integer ELSE 0 END), conversation.""firstName"", conversation.id DESC"
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 37kB
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=454.80..351397.28 rows=86438 width=1742) (actual time=12.856..128302.754 rows=1387007 loops=1)
"              Hash Cond: (conversation.""teamBotLocationId"" = ""teamBotLocation"".id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using ""conversation_teambot_teambotLocation_email"" on conversation  (cost=0.56..350499.44 rows=86438 width=1706) (actual time=1.165..127696.780 rows=1387007 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((""teamBotId"" = 'f92eb170-28b2-11ed-a128-098b9f10e3d6'::uuid) AND (""teamBotLocationId"" = ANY ('{f9978ff0-28b3-11ed-a128-098b9f10e3d6,f1e505b0-f033-11ed-b347-43d7d9fb1309}'::uuid[])))"
"                    Filter: ((NOT ""isDeleted"") AND (NOT ""isBlocked"") AND (NOT ""isBroadcast"") AND (NOT ""isGroup""))"
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 6940
              ->  Hash  (cost=434.66..434.66 rows=1566 width=32) (actual time=11.677..11.678 rows=1566 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 115kB
"                    ->  Seq Scan on ""teamBotLocation""  (cost=0.00..434.66 rows=1566 width=32) (actual time=0.004..11.326 rows=1566 loops=1)"
Planning Time: 35.488 ms
Execution Time: 130014.015 ms
```

I need a solution that executes the query in under 1-2s keeping in mind that the sorting can be done in either ascending or descending order for these 5 columns `firstName`, `lastName`, `phone`, `email` and `createdAt`.

**Note **-

1. If any row has an empty string in a particular column, it should keep that row at the last while sorting.
2. To keep in mind, all these conversations belong to different accounts in a 1-to-1 mapping. So technically this query is for a particular account. Also each account can have different locations. So the conversations also has a 1-to-1 mapping with these locations.

Comment: Could you please post the query plan in plain text in your question?

Comment: I would start by making sure this index is available: `create index ix1 on conversation (teamBotId, isDeleted, isBlocked, isBroadcast, isGroup) include (teamBotLocationId);`.

Comment: I removed the plan as an image. Please post it as text.

Comment: In *all* cases, you need to ensure you have a covering index *AND* that your query can use it. Applying functions and transformations to WHERE or ORDER BY columns prevents the database from using indexes. The values you ask the database to sort by don't exist in any index. That `CASE WHEN` can't use any indexes covering `firstname` and frankly, doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to sort empty strings last?

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but has an impact on your sorting: Why do you store an empty string for firstName instead of a NULL? With a NULL you just use NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST and you're done. Now you must use a CASE that makes indexing useless.

Comment: Either store the empty strings as NULL in the first place, or add an additional column "firstname_is_null". Either will allow you to index the columns the way you want them ordered, and avoid the CASE expression.

Comment: @FrankHeikens as requested, i have added the query plan in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer assumes that `"firstName"` is a column of `conversation`. Otherwise, there is little hope for your query.

You can simplify the `ORDER BY` clause to

```
ORDER BY conversation."firstName" = '',
         conversation."firstName",
         conversation.id DESC
```

because `FALSE < TRUE`.

Then you need an index to support the `ORDER BY` clause (and, in part, the `WHERE` condition):

```
CREATE INDEX ON conversation (
   "teamBotId",
   ("firstName" = ''),
   "firstName",
   id DESC
);
```

and an index for the nested loop join (on `"teamBotLocation".id`, but if that is the primary key, you already have an index there).

If you need to support different `ORDER BY` clauses, you need an index for each of these. Yes, that is expensive and will slow down data modifications. But if you need these queries to be fast, that's the price you have to pay.

Comment: this command - CREATE INDEX ON conversation ("teamBotId","firstName" = '', "firstName",id DESC); doesn't seem to be valid. The error comes in "firstName"=''. Also my postgres version is 11.19.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. The second index column requires parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort firstly the firstName column with limit 10 and just after that to sort the result table with the four other columns
sorting  10 rows is much more quickly